# Effects of turning off ARC in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to use a framework which does not use `ARC` and it seems that I have to turn this feature off before I can use it. My question is, what are the potential ramifications of doing so? If I turn this off, what will I have to do to my current code to make sure I don't have any memory leak or any other issues in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ARC works fine with static libraries that use manual reference counting. If you're copying a bunch of .m files into your project, though, that's a different story. Fortunately, it's pretty easy to [turn off ARC for specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project); you should do that for the files in that framework and leave your own files using ARC.

Comment: Thanks! I'm adding 1 .m & its corresponding .m file. So that should work okay then?

Comment: Yup. Just turn off ARC for that .m file (it doesn't matter for a .h) using the technique described in the post I linked.

Comment: That's what accepting an answer is for. :^) (It's the outlined checkmark below the upvote/downvote arrows.)

Comment: You answered too quick! Lol... I tried to accept, but told me I had to wait 6 minutes. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry, the guy I answered right before you had a reputation of about 3, and I mixed you two up.